Priority of payment of decedent's debt to different government agencies
31 U.S. Code § 3713(1)(B) (Priority of Government Claims) reads in part:

A claim of the United States Government shall be paid first when . . .
the estate of a deceased debtor, in the custody of the executor or
administrator, is not enough to pay all debts of the debtor.

This most often applies to income and estate taxes of a decedent and their estate, which take priority over unsecured debt or any beneficiaries’ inheritance.
But what happens if the decedent and/or the estate owes money to more than one U.S. government agency? For example, the IRS for taxes and the Small Business Administration as a sole proprietor who took a non-forgivable disaster loan, and there are not enough funds to settle all the debt? The IRS is part of the Treasury Department but the SBA is an independent agency of the U.S. government, not under Treasury even though it moves funds through Treasury.
Assume that there are no complications imposed by tax liens or specific findings or orders of a federal court.
Would the executor be required to allocate payment in proportion to the amount of federal debt owed separately to each government agency? Or could the executor treat all government debt as equal, and, for example, pay off the SBA loan in full, pay the remainder of available funds to the IRS, and then inform the IRS that the estate is now insolvent and the remaining debt will not be paid?

united-states
Apart from this statute, state probate law controls. State probate statutes have some priorities (most notably treating tax debts generally different from non-tax debts), but typically lump far more debts into the same categories than bankruptcy law does. Also, secured claims (e.g. mortgages, car loans, margin loans) generally have priority in their collateral over all other claims.
For example, in Colorado, the priority of claims is as follows:

§ 15-12-805. Classification of claims
(1) The personal representative shall pay allowed claims against the
estate of a decedent in the following order:
(a) Property held by or in the possession of the deceased person as
fiduciary or trustee of a trust, which shall include a resulting
trust, as long as the reasonable expenses of administering such
property and of investigating and determining such claim, as provided
by section 15-10-602, but subject to section 15-10-605, shall be paid
from such property as determined by the court;
(b) Other costs and expenses of administration;
(c) Reasonable funeral and final disposition expenses;
(d) Debts and taxes with preference under federal law;
(e) Reasonable and necessary medical and hospital expenses of the last
illness of the decedent, including compensation of persons attending
him or her;
(f) Debts and taxes with preference under other laws of this state;
(f.5) The claim of the department of health care policy and financing
for the net amount of medical assistance, as defined in section
25.5-4-302(5), C.R.S., paid to or for the decedent;
(f.7) The claim of a county department of human or social services,
the state department of human services, or the department of early
childhood for the excess public assistance, including child care
assistance, paid or provided for which the recipient was ineligible;
(g) Any child support obligations of the decedent that were due and
unpaid at death in accordance with a valid court order or agreement of
record in which the decedent was a party, and any future child support
obligations of the decedent as determined by the court;
(h) All other claims.
(2) No preference shall be given in the payment of any claim over any
other claim of the same class, and a claim due and payable shall not
be entitled to a preference over claims not due.

The general rule is that debts with the same priority are paid pro-rata, and claims of the U.S. Government subject to 31 U.S.C. § 3713(1)(B) are governed by Colo. Rev. Stat. § 15-12-805(1)(d).
But, this is a little bit more complicated because virtually all agencies and instrumentalities of the U.S. government (in contrast to a U.S. sponsored corporation which isn't the United States government and doesn't benefit from 31 U.S.C. § 3713(1)(B)), are legally the same person. One U.S. government agency can't sue another, and ultimately, who payments are credited against different specific debts owed to the same person is not well defined.
For example, an SBA loan is usually made by a bank with a guarantee from the federal government small business administration, but is not itself a debt to the federal government. Likewise, a debt owed to, e.g., FannieMae (a federal mortgage lending corporation) is not a debt owed to the U.S. government, even though it has a federal connection.
Usually, if the debtor is dead and insolvent, it doesn't really matter what gets applied to what, but if there is a third-party co-debtor, it could be quite important.
Ultimately, if the total amount paid to the United States government is correct, the U.S. government really has no room to complain, so the executor arguably has some freedom to decide which of the federal debts to pay, as long as the total share of the U.S. government is correct.

The same class of creditor receive the same amount in the dollar
australia
This is covered by s108 of the Bankruptcy Act 1966.

Except as otherwise provided by this Act, all debts proved in a bankruptcy rank equally and, if the proceeds of the property of the bankrupt are insufficient to meet them in full, they shall be paid proportionately.

This is true of all bankruptcies, not just deceased estates. A similar provision in the Corporations Act make this the case for company liquidations.
The priority of creditors is governed by s109 which lists nine classes (making ten overall with the “everybody else class”). In Australia, government debt is not special and ranks with the rest of the unsecured creditors in tenth place except for unpaid Workers Compensation debt which ranks sixth, in between the first and final tranches of wages to employees.

Is "the same amount in the dollar" the same as "paid proportionately" as Australian law states? Did you mean to say "the same percentage ON the dollar"? Dale, I totally support answers that explain the law for other jurisdictions, but this answer does not seem useful because it ignores the nexus of the question: is indebtedness to all government departments at the same level of priority essentially fungible because it’s all indebtedness to the same government no matter which department? Can this answer be improved to answer that question?
